# CTools Modal AJAX Webform onchange submit problem

Tags: ajax, webforms, forms, chaos-tool-suite

I want to submit form on radio button change, it works, but form is submitted twice and i got JSON error on confirmation page.

I'm using this function:

```
function surveySubmit() {
  $("form").one("click", "input:radio", function(){
    $("form input[type=submit]").click();
  });
}
```

Comment: are you using ctools [modal form](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms) or anything else?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Modal Forms